# Containers (Kubernetes) vs Web service (REST APIs)

Tags: rest, web-services, kubernetes, containers

I have a single screen desktop application developed in Java. It is a tool to convert files, given a file in .abc format, the tool converts it to .xyz format. Basically the tool works offline and acts as a translator to convert file from one form to another.

So now, to improve the infrastructure, there are discussions to move the tool to Kubernetes or to provide REST services for the file conversion. I completely have no idea about the containers nor the REST APIs as I am a front-end developer.

More about the tool, as I told earlier, the tool is a single page application, very light doing very minimal job, totally used by 200 users approximately. So, this being the shape and size of the application, which one would be the best approach to go with and why? Basically, I am looking for a short evaluation report of Kubernetes vs REST service and architecture recommendation with reasons.

Comment: You can run a REST service on kubernetes just fine, so this is not an either/or situation. What problem are you trying to solve? Most people don't need Kubernetes. It's quite a complex system to understand and it really just benefits the 1% largest installations. There's many simpler things before it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your application is a standalone application which is quite an old concept.
I can mention high-level changes needs to be done when your file conversion logic would be exposed over Rest Api in Kubernetes world.

you can go through one by one following mentioned areas to get a better understanding design-wise:

1. java code would be a backend code and its public methods that take inputs from UI actions will be exposed over rest API.
   There are multiple rest API's (jersey, rest easy, etc or spring/spring-boot framework also provides rest API support) that you can go through any of them to get an understanding.
2. once your backend is exposed over the rest API then it needs to be containerized means your backend will be running under the container. Can go through docker documentation and can build one sample containerized app. There is huge material present in this area.
3. once your backend is containerized then it will be installed in a Kubernetes cluster
   Kubernetes is basically a container orchestration tool and it's quite a wide thing. you can through its official documentation for basic understanding.
4. SPA will be running on a client machine like today also you are able to launch from your desktop but it will communicate with the Kubernetes cluster where your application is presently packaged in a container.

References:
docker :
https://docs.docker.com/

Kubernetes :
https://kubernetes.io/